# ClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException in SpringBoot app

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an SpringBoot app., a basic web skeleton app using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine.

with this pom.xml with this dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring data -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Email dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Webjars for JQuery and Bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7-1</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

This application properties file:

```
# Spring Data JPA properties

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

but when I start the app. I got this error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

15413 [main] INFO  c.d.DevopsbuddyApplication - Starting DevopsbuddyApplication on MacBook-Pro-de-calzada.local with PID 80844 (/Users/nunito/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/devopsbuddy/target/classes started by nunito in /Users/nunito/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/devopsbuddy)
15416 [main] DEBUG c.d.DevopsbuddyApplication - Running with Spring Boot v1.5.3.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.8.RELEASE

    17325 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    17341 [main] WARN  o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
    17347 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.devopsbuddy.DevopsbuddyApplication.main(DevopsbuddyApplication.java:10)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.createJpaVendorAdapter(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:103)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22397ccc.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$6(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22397ccc$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fbd62950.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22397ccc.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 60 common frames omitted
```

I also tried `mvn clean install -U`

the results of  mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building devopsbuddy 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.194 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ devopsbuddy ---
[INFO] com.devopsbuddy:devopsbuddy:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.194:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.webjars:bootstrap:jar:3.3.7-1:compile
[INFO] \- org.webjars:jquery:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.189 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-23T20:10:12+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you please post full `pom.xml`. Also, what command do you use to run application?

Comment: Do you have other files in your application?

Comment: no, I don't have other files

Comment: Try deleting your maven cache (.m2/repository) or run mvn clean install -U. If this doesn't work, post output of mvn dependency:tree for hibernate.

Comment: Your dependencies look correct. Are you using  intellij to run this? You may need to empty the cache of intellij as well. Alternatively, try running with the packaged jar maven builds. In intellij, you can also try searching for HibernateException (CTRL+N) and see if it is resolved and where it is.

Comment: As @RomanCherepanov asked, could you provide the full pom.xml. The reason for this question is because of two ways you can set up spring boot. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven

If you use the first approach chapter 13.2.1 Spring boot will use a dependencies management pom under water to provide you with the correct set of dependencies. Which can be found for each version here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No, and I have this warning in the pom file "Duplicating managed version l for hibernate-core"

Comment: For me it worked after deleting the <user>.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core directory. I had an invalid jar and after mvn install it downloaded the jar again. No need to add that in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue with the following POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dzone.springboot.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>dzone-springboot-mysql-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>dzone-springboot-mysql-test</name>
    <description>Testing out Spring Boot and MySQL</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the output from `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ dzone-springboot-mysql-test ---
[INFO] dzone.springboot.mysql:dzone-springboot-mysql-test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
. . .
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
. . .
```

This is the (relevant) stacktrace I get:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-11-22 11:52:04 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.outputConditionEvaluationReport(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
. . . 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 85 common frames omitted
```

As I've been experimenting a bit with spring boot lately, I've discovered that for many dependencies the starter project functionality does not playnice with the dependency handling, except for Spring Boot `1.4.1.RELEASE`. When I changed Spring Boot version like this:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

... it all works perfectly. As one might expect, `mvn dependency:tree` reveals the dependency changes. Here's a unified diff view of the changes:

```
--- /home/rick/projects/dzone-springboot-mysql-test/tree.1.4.1.RELEASE.txt
+++ /home/rick/projects/dzone-springboot-mysql-test/tree.1.5.6.RELEASE.txt
@@ -27,66 +6,65 @@
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ dzone-springboot-mysql-test ---
 [INFO] dzone.springboot.mysql:dzone-springboot-mysql-test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
-[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
+[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
+[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
+[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
+[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
-[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.5:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.5:compile
-[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.16:compile
+[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.16:compile
+[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile
-[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
-[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
-[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
-[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
-[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
-[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
+[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.43:compile
+[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.6.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
+[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
+[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
+[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
+[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
+[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
 [INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
 [INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
 [INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
 [INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
 [INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
-[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:test
+[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
 [INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
 [INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
 [INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
 [INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
-[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
-[INFO]    |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:test
-[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:test
+[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
+[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
+[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:test
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-[INFO] Total time: 3.699 s
-[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-22T12:02:08-05:00
-[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/252M
+[INFO] Total time: 1.525 s
+[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-22T12:02:29-05:00
+[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/429M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Summarizing the changes:

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE
downgraded to
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE

org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final
downgraded to
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final

org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.6.RELEASE
downgraded to
org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.3.RELEASE

At this point I'm not entirely sure which fixed the classpath but now springboot is happily loading the context.

**UPDATE**: here's a link to the code: https://github.com/rbuitragoc/dzone-springboot-mysql-test

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and I found that the latest spring-data-jpa of spring boot 2.0.0 jar is not compatible with hibernate-core jar
The solution on my side was downgrade the project to older version of spring boot , so from 2.0.0 tp 1.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The above comments about downgrading are absolutely right.It seems that spring boot version does not handle dependency version between spring data and hibernate core correctly. By downgrading to spring boot 1.5.5 all errors are gone

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had

```
        <spring.version>5.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

as well as:

```
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
```

Which caused a conflict.

Removing `spring.version` fixed it.